# How to shorten the labels on y axis and replace them with short forms in achartengine bar chart

Tags: android, achartengine

I am working on achartengine bar chart. The values on y axis are in billions. There is not enough space to accommodate these values as the value goes out of the screen. I want to change 1000 into K, million into M ,  so that values get easily accommodated on the screen. Please suggest any way how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no standart method or any way to do this. 
If you really need this, download source code and modify it. You will have to customise Renderer class.

Or you can do this:

```
        // rendered
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer rootRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        rootRenderer.setBarSpacing(1);

        rootRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        rootRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, "1k");
        rootRenderer.addXTextLabel(2, "2k");
```